# Is 'non-work' a word?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, american-english, morphology

I'm working in a big company with lots of employees.
We have 'Skype for business application with which we communicate and interact with each other .
I want to update my status to something like:

> I'm not willing to answer **non-work** messages.

I want to know whether there are better alternatives.

Comment: The "I am not willing" bit sounds abrupt and borderline rude but the message itself is grammatically acceptable. I would ask whether there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonwork) nonwork is an actual word, wih the exact meaning you just defined. The only differnce is, that it is written together, without the "-" symbol. As for the phrasing of it, for me something like: "Work related only." or "Work related only please." sounds a bit better. I think, anyone using Skype for business would understand that by this you mean that only important, work questions problems will be addressed.